# Помогите, пожалуйста, еще с одним массивом, нужно получить title

Tags: php

```
array(2) { ["count"]=> int(1) ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(7) { ["peer"]=> array(3) { ["id"]=> int(2000000003) ["type"]=> string(4) "chat" ["local_id"]=> int(3) } ["in_read"]=> int(0) ["out_read"]=> int(0) ["last_message_id"]=> int(0) ["can_write"]=> array(1) { ["allowed"]=> bool(true) } ["chat_settings"]=> array(9) { ["acl"]=> array(7) { ["can_change_info"]=> bool(true) ["can_change_invite_link"]=> bool(false) ["can_change_pin"]=> bool(true) ["can_invite"]=> bool(true) ["can_promote_users"]=> bool(false) ["can_see_invite_link"]=> bool(false) ["can_moderate"]=> bool(true) } ["owner_id"]=> int(454598412) ["state"]=> string(2) "in" ["title"]=> string(15) "シンシティ" ["active_ids"]=> array(4) { [0]=> int(429656448)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $data["title"];
```

Или в цикле:

```
foreach ($data as $value) {
    echo $value["title"];
}
```

Comment: Не забудь переменную $data поменять на свою

Comment: Чтобы так просто было, не выводит так...

Comment: Скинь часть кода...

Comment: foreach ($garr_users['items'] as $item) {
if($item['chat_settings'])  {
$memberid = $item['title'] ;
}
}